# Adium says I have unread messages but I don't see them

Tags: macos, mac, adium

I'm running Adium v 1.4b8 on Mac OS X 10.5.whatever and the dock icon shows that there are two alerts, however there aren't any authorization requests visible or anything showing up when I open the messages window to send a message to a contact.

When I try to quite the app it asks me if I'm sure since I have two unread messages.

How do I either see what these are or make them go away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just happened to me; the solution is to open up preferences, go the the advanced tab, Message Alerts; uncheck and then re-check the "Animate the dock icon" and "Display a message count badge" check boxes.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the [challengeRespose plugin](http://www.adiumxtras.com/index.php?a=xtras&xtra_id=6177), if you have it installed. happened to me for the first time today. so it should be ok to ignore.